# A complemented subspace without basis of a space with a basis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $E$ be a Banach space with basis. Is it possible to find examples such that $S \subset E$ be a complemented subspace without basis?

Comment: [This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2048451?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) looks relevant.

Comment: The paper of Szarek, mentioned in the above link (and giving an affirmative answer to your question) is: Szarek, S. J. A Banach space without a basis which has the bounded approximation property.
Acta Math. 159 (1987), no. 1-2, 81-98.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The paper: Szarek, S. J. *A Banach space without a basis which has the bounded approximation property*. Acta Math. 159 (1987), no. 1-2, 81-98, provides an example heralded by the title.

A separable Banach space $X$ has the bounded approximation property if and only if  $X$ is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of a space with a basis. This result can be found in Classical Banach Spaces, Vol.1, Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri (Theorem 1.e.13).